# Sort same rows in sql request by name and not by date between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

My full question described on picture. Now i have 2 same rows in one date. 09.07.2016. They are same by TITLE not buy date. i need to group them, echo only one row but with quantity 2.

How i can edit my request?

[image: My question in described on this picture]

And here is the request:

```
SELECT * FROM cupons 
 WHERE YEAR(dateadd) = YEAR(NOW()) 
   AND MONTH(dateadd)=MONTH(NOW()) 
   AND referer='$user[idreferer]' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are after something like GROUP BY. Here is a simple example

```
SELECT 
    col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
FROM 
    cupons
WHERE 
    YEAR(dateadd) = YEAR(NOW())
    AND MONTH(dateadd) = MONTH(NOW()) 
    AND referer = '$user[idreferer]'
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use group by and aggegate function count(*) or sum(your_column) (depend is you want the count of the row or the sum of the column values in rows)

```
  SELECT col1, col2, ... count(*) FROM cupons 
  WHERE YEAR(dateadd) = YEAR(NOW()) 
  AND    MONTH(dateadd)=MONTH(NOW()) 
  AND referer='$user[idreferer]' 
  ORDER BY id DESC
  Group By col1, col2, ...
```